# How to make a visible TS3 bot with server query

Tags: python, teamspeak

I am trying to create a teamspeak bot. I have done something, it is working and now I am wondering how to make the bot visible. Now I have just a server query script, the result looks like this:

[image]

It is just a server query and the user **has to have it enabled** (the active button on the right side of toolkit bar) to see him. How can I make it like a normal client? Visible all the time, able to poke and write. Something like a ordinary music bot, but without the music...

Thanks, Rasty

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SOLUTION: Server Query is just a server query. It is possible to work with the server via SQ, but pretending being real user must be done by running the TS3 client on a remote server. Just like a real client. There is no easy way to simulate a user.